# ClassNotFoundException when trying to add configuration to a CompositeConfiguration using commons-configuration2

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-commons, databricks

I'm using `org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2` to load and merge configuration from different sources:

```
val root = CompositeConfiguration()
root.addConfiguration(SystemConfiguration())

val configurations = Configurations()


root.addConfiguration(configurations.properties("defaults.properties"))
```

My problem is that whenever I run this code I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanIntrospector     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)     at
>   org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.createParametersProxy(Parameters.java:294)    at
>   org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Parameters.fileBased(Parameters.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileParams(Configurations.java:602)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileParams(Configurations.java:638)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.fileBasedBuilder(Configurations.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.propertiesBuilder(Configurations.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.fluent.Configurations.properties(Configurations.java:318)
>     at io.sspinc.datahub.sparkapp.MainKt.main(main.kt:18) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanIntrospector     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

It says that `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanIntrospector` is not found. If I add `commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3` to the classpath the problem is solved but the main problem is that **I'm using Apache Spark 2.3.0 in a managed environment (Databricks)** and it comes with `commons-beanutils:1.7.0` so I can't do anything about the beanutils version.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: and what happen when you add `commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.7.0` to the classpath ?

Comment: Same error. In the docs config2 says it only works with `1.9.3` or later. If I use `commons-configurations:1.10` instead I do not get the exception.

Comment: can you exclude explicitly `commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.7.0` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using `commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10` if you only want the composite configuration feature form *commons-configuration*. It works like this:

```
val root = CompositeConfiguration()
root.addConfiguration(SystemConfiguration())

root.addConfiguration(PropertiesConfiguration("defaults.properties"))
```

Configurations 2 won't work with `1.7.0` bean utils according to [their documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/dependencies.html).